# VBS create a file to each row of .csv

Tags: csv, vbscript, macros

I am a begginer with vbscript and I need to do one but It's not working. I need to create a Vbs that creates files for every row of a .csv file, but that new files have to have the name of the first colunm.

The csv below for example. I need to create a file with each rows content but the name of the new files have to be the name of each first colunm, "File1.txt"..."File4.txt"..."File3.docx".

```
File1.txt   Whatever0
File4.txt   Whatever4
File3.docx  Whatever3
File7.csv   Whatever9
File.xsl    Whatever1
```

This is the .vbs I have up to now

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim destinationFolderName
destinationFolderName = "C:\Vbs_Files\OUT"
Set destinationFolder =  objFSO.GetFolder(destinationFolderName)
Dim originalFolderName
originalFolderName = "C:\Vbs_Files\Excel"

Set originalFolder =  objFSO.GetFolder(originalFolderName)

Do Until objInput.AtEndOfStream
line = objInput.ReadLine
IF line <> "" Then

Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(destinationFolder & colunm(0)) 
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Vbs_Files\Temp" & colunm(1))

FileSystemObject.CopyFile "C:\Vbs_Files\Temp", "C:\Vbs_Files\OUT"

End if

Loop
```

Could you help me with this?

Comment: Debug  you code step by step and can you please share the error or the problem that you are facing. You mentioned its not working what is happening currently when you run the code. Please share

Comment: Please explain more : Did you want to create just empty files with names of first colunm or something else like put the second colunm into the file created as contents ??

Comment: The file contents have to be the line of the .csv, for example in line 1:   File Content: "File1.txt Whatever0" --------- File Name: "File1.txt"